# Why does EF core ignore auto increment column and try to update this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In mssql database I have an auto increment column named *AutoIncrementNumber*
which is configured with this mentioned

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
   {
      entity.Property(e =>e.AutoIncrementNumber).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}
```

I added a new user and want to update this

```
    var user = new User { UserName = "SomeUserName", Code=0};
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "SomePassword");

    //after CreateAsync user.AutoIncrementNumber == 1

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
      user.Code = 1;
      userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }
```

but during UpdateAsync I came across with an error

**DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 
SqlException: Cannot update identity column 'AutoIncrementNumber'**

Project is running under .net core 1.1

SQL Schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [AutoIncrementNumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReferralCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [Id] ASC )WITH (
            PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
            IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
            ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Can you also add what are we doing inside CreateAsync and UpdateAsync methods?

Comment: I am using standard methods of _userManager = UserManager<User>() provided by Microsoft

Comment: @GurgenSargsyan `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` doesn't mean `IDENTITY`, it means the value will be generated by the server when adding the column. It doesn't say anything about updating. It could be IDENTITY or it could use a default value from a SEQUENCE. What you do here is uncommon. EF works just fine with auto-generated *key* properties. You are using `AutoIncrementNumber` as if it were a calculated column though

Comment: Try [ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/valuegeneratedonaddorupdate-method)  instead

Answer (score 5):

[ValueGeneratedOnAdd](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/valuegeneratedonadd-method) means that the value is generated by the database when inserting an object and the property should be ignored when inserting.

You should use [ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/valuegeneratedonaddorupdate-method) to specify that the value should be excluded from UPDATE as well.

With Data Annotations, the equivalent to `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` is `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`. The equivalent to `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` is `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Check the [Generated Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) section in Microsoft Docs.